# Bounce rate segmentation

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I want to segment an event label together with its bounce rate. I create  a segment condition regular expression with two conditionals: one for the event label and the other for the bounce. For this last one, I search the dimesion Bounces, but I don´t know what value to put in. Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to separate out with this segment? Events and bounces are an unusual combination.

Comment: I am trying to find out the next scenario: every time the user clicks the button Match result in a bettting game, what frequency of bounce rate appears

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult segment to get at; you will have to kind of circle around it, and may or may not get the exact numbers you are hoping for.

Bounces are not what you are looking for - a bounced session is a session consisting of only one hit, and if your session includes a pageview and an event (as I assume it does) it will never be a bounce. In addition, the dimension `Bounces` (as opposed to the metric `Bounce Rate`) is a User-level dimension, so you will get all sessions from users who had the number of bounced sessions you specify for `Bounces`.

What I would try is a sequence segment that gets at sessions where the only instance of the event is the final hit of the session. You will have two filters, one 1-step sequence and one 2-step sequence. The 1-step sequence will include sessions in which your event occurs. The 2-step sequence will exclude sessions in which your event is followed by a page containing `/`. Example screenshot from Google's demo account attached:

[image: Screenshot of segment setup on Google demo GA]

The idea here is to include sessions in which the event occurred, but exclude sessions in which the event was followed by any other hit. Every hit on a website includes a Page setting, which will always include a forward slash (unless you have things filtered to change that).

Do note that this will exclude any session in which your event occurs as a non-final hit, even if it **also** occurs as the final hit - it will select the sessions in which your event happened once, and nothing happened after it. That is the closest equivalent to Bounce Rate for an event, though, I would say.

I don't know a way to allow any number of repetitions of the event but then also require one of them be the final hit of the session. You could make additional segments catching additional fixed numbers of event hits, but that will not get you the general number.

You can also compare two segments to get a sense of when people are not proceeding; this will work best if there is a specific event they should be triggering or page they should be viewing after the event you're considering. You would make a segment for sessions in which your event occurs, and a second segment for sessions in which your event occurs and is followed by the hit that signals they are proceeding (the "non-bounces", in a sense). By comparing how many sessions are in the second segment versus the first you can get a sense of drop-off, but the gap between them is still going to be sessions in which the event happened only once, not all sessions in which the event was the last hit.

Comment: Oh! thanks for the explanation. I will read it deeply and if I have any doubt I will tell you. Have a nice day :)